# PHP mail function sends out the email, but the AJAX function errors out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, email

I am using "mail" on PHP, and it successfully sends out the email.
However, I am getting an error on my AJAX's success/error function.
I am keep getting an alert "Email Failed".
Thank you in advance.

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $emailTo = "test@test.com";
    $emailSubject = "Email Test";
    $emailBody = "Check Email";
    if(mail($emailTo, $emailSubject, $emailBody))
        echo "success";
    else
        echo "fail";
?>
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    url:'email_data.php',
    type:'post',
    data:$('#postForm').serialize(),
    success:function(res)
    {
        if(res=="success")
            alert("Email Sent");
        else
            alert("Email Not Sent");
    },
    error:function()
    {
        alert("Email Failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Change your `error:function()` to `error:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown): ` and inside the error function, do an `alert(xhr.responseText);`

Comment: I did... but I am getting a blank.

Comment: Check the content of the AJAX response, is there anything there?

Comment: Did you show us your PHP Code as it it? Because if so, you're not echo-ing anything from your PHP.

Comment: I have updated my code... This was the original code I had but since it wasn't working I took out the echo and the AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
success:function(res)
{
    if(res=="successful")
        alert("Email Sent");
```

should be:

```
success:function(res)
{
    if(res=="success")
        alert("Email Sent");
```

This is because you are `echo`ing success in your PHP file.

Comment: sorry... it was a typo. It is "success" but still getting error alert.